# How to COPY/ADD file into current WORKDIR in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

COPY/ADD statement requires 2 parameters. How can I add any file to current workdir that has been set in base image?

```
FROM company/app
COPY local.conf
```

Sure I can add WORKDIR statement before COPY to explicitly declare it. But that would be problematic if the workdir in `company/app` changes.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It turns out to be very simple. I just need to use dot to copy to current workdir.

```
COPY local.conf .
```

Still cannot figure out if this has some gotchas. But it just work as intended.

Comment: That should be correct. Don't think there are any gotchas. You are using a relative path to the WORKDIR as described in [the docs for COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Answer (score 5):

#### Addition to the accepted answer

The [docs for COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) has a few use cases that worth extra attention.

One of them is relevant to our use case:

> If multiple  resources are specified, either directly or due to
> the use of a wildcard, then  must be a directory, and it must
> end with a slash /.

So, **for cases that more then one file** is copied, the destination must be a **directory** and **end with a `/`**.

```
FROM company/app
WORKDIR app
COPY *.conf ./ # <-- Here
```

In case we'll write the last line has:

```
COPY *.conf .
```

We'll get the following error:

> When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must
> be a directory and end with a /

Answer (score 1):

> But that would be problematic if the workdir in company/app changes.

Then you would need to pass that workdir as build-time parameter in order to be able to change it from one docker build to the next.
See docker [`build --build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg)

You would need first to [`docker inspect company/app`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) (inspec the image) to see if there are any changes.